# Como baixar um arquivo através do download do navegador com C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Eu tenho uma aplicação MVC Razor Pages, nessa aplicação eu salvo arquivos no banco de dados MySQL definindo como longblob, preciso que o cliente aperte no botão de "Download" e o navegador pergunte para ele onde salvar o arquivo, e consequentemente salvar, tentei através do WriteAllBytes mas não consegui.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> getFile(string codProjeto)
    {
        ArrayList diretorio = new ArrayList();
        var arquivo = _context.anexo.Where(x => x.COD_PROJETO == Int32.Parse(codProjeto)).ToArray();
        diretorio.Add(@"C:\Users\Miguel\Downloads\" + arquivo[0].DS_NOME);

        await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(diretorio[0].ToString(), arquivo[0].DS_ANEXO);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: System.IO.File é utilizado para a máquina que esta executando o código. ou seja, isso irá gravar um arquivo no seu servidor e não na máquina do cliente.

Comment: Voce deve deixar o navegador cuidar disso para voce. Se o seu endpoint esta retornando uma View, o navegador espera que seja retornado html.  No seu caso, voce deve retornar o arquivo mesmo. De uma olhada nessa resposta: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/72948065/12429763](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72948065/12429763)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar um dos métodos: [DownloadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-8.0) ou [DownloadFileTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync?view=net-8.0) da classe [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-8.0)
Exemplo:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getFile(string codProjeto)
    {
     ArrayList diretorio = new ArrayList();
     var arquivo = _context.anexo.Where(x => x.COD_PROJETO == Int32.Parse(codProjeto)).ToArray();
     string localFilePath = @"C:\Users\Miguel\Downloads\" + arquivo.DS_NOME;

   // WebClient
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
      // Baixa o arquivo da URL especificada
      await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("URL_DO_SEU_ARQUIVO"), localFilePath);
    }
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: A classe WebClient não é mais recomendada para desenvolvimento. Use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0) ao invés disso.